# Increase tolerance on Eevee render so objects don't overlap?

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I'm currently trying to render out a flythrough of some LED fixtures on a building facade via eevee. (See Below)

[image]

The problem is i'm getting an unwanted flicker when I output the animation, upon investigation I found the flickering seems to be due to objects overlapping in the viewport (even though they're actually 50mm apart).(See Below)
[image]

Although in cycles it seems to render correctly though with no overlapping.(See Below)
[image]

Is there a setting i'm missing for Eevee to so that it will render as it does in cycles? I've tried increasing the samples but it doesnt seem to get rid of the flickering...

Any help would be appreciated thank you

Comment: Hello :). This is sometimes caused by too large *clipping range* of your camera lens. Just lower the distance between *clip start/end*. Also bear in mind, the 3D view precision is better near the *clip start* distance.